# P(R) is contained in Nil(R) for noncommutative rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

> How to show that $P(R)$ is contained in $\operatorname{Nil}(R)$ (where $R$ is a **noncommutative** ring with identity)?

Definitions I am using:

- A *nil right ideal* is one whose elements are all nilpotent.
- A *prime ideal* is a two sided ideal which satisfies the property: $aRb$ contained in $I$ implies $a$ is in $I$ or $b$ is in $I$.
- $P(R)$ is the intersection of all prime ideals.
- $\operatorname{Nil}(R)$ is the sum of all right nil ideals of $R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy since $P(R)$ is a nil ideal. Happily, this can be seen using ideas from the commutative theory.

### Proof

Suppose to the contrary that $x\in P(R)$ isn't nilpotent. Then $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\dots\}$ is a multiplicatively closed system disjoint from $\{0\}$. Using the usual Zorn's lemma argument, find an ideal $I$ which is maximal with respect to being disjoint from the powers of $x$.

We first contend that $I$ is a prime ideal. Let $aRb\subseteq I$ with $a,b\notin I$. By maximality, $x^n\in RaR+I$ for some $n$, and $x^k\in RbR+I$ for some $k$. But then $x^{n+k}\in(RaR+I)(RbR+I)\subseteq I$, a contradiction. Thus at least one of $a,b$ is in $I$, proving the primeness of $I$.

But the existence of this prime ideal $I$ disjoint from the powers of $x$ witnesses that $x\notin P(R)$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $x$ is nilpotent.

Thus $P(R)$ is a nil ideal, and is thus trivially contained in $Nil(R)$.

---

Comment: The noncommutative analogue of a multiplicatively closed set is called an "m-system." A subset $S$ of $R$ is an m-system if, for any two elements $a,b\in S$, there exists an $r\in R$ such that $arb\in S$. Every multiplicatively closed set is an m-system, but not conversely. An ideal is prime iff its complement is an m-system, and an ideal maximal wrt to being disjoint from an m-system is prime. These are very nice (and rare) parallels to the commutative case :)